# Thread priority android

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool

In my app I'm looking for a design where I've 2 threads:

- **Primary thread** with high priority, downloads data that is urgent
- **Background thread** with very low priority, keeps on downloading data in background and uses less resources

Also,I want to manage these threads via queue or stack so that I can push operations in these 2 threads whenever I want. How should I go about this ? Thanks !

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use ExecutorService , it will help you manage thread pool.
you can execute your task by input Runnable or Callable